# Pass two arrays with a condition in rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an association between two tables, Users and Posts. I have to get all the rows from the two tables where user.name belongs to an array and post.title belongs to another array.

I tried doing it this way but I get errors.

```
User.includes(:posts).where('user.name' => user_name_array AND 'post.title' => post_title_array)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

User.includes(:posts).where('users.name in (?) and posts.title in (?)', user_name_array, post_title_array)

Comment: Thanks NikDP. What magic does paranthesis around question mark do?

Comment: For IN query we have to pass the data in parenthesis. e.g. User.where("id in (1,2,3,4,5)") or User.where("id in (?)",[1,2,3,4,5])

Comment: What to do if one of the conditions is to check time range??

Comment: To check the time range use BETWEEN Clause.

Comment: e.g. User.where(:created_at => (params[:start_date].to_date)..(params[:end_date].to_date)

Comment: I asked what if one of the conditions is array and another is range. I know what to do if I have to query using range

Comment: Go through the above referred link then you will understand how to write multiple conditions in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
User.joins(:posts).where('users.name in ? and posts.title in ?', user_name_array, post_title_array)
```

Comment: Sorry @Sachin R It didn't work. Even if it works I want to get only the rows where the two conditions meet but not filter the rows fetched by one condition

Comment: U mean to say you need all the users object?

Comment: didn't get you? can you elaborate?

Comment: Means you need all the users which matches the name in the user_name_array and having post title match post_title_array?

Comment: yeach...that's exactly what i want in a single query